# Is it possible to backup a database on desktop without modifying the server permissions?

Tags: c#, sql

So this is my problem, I want to backup a database on desktop or any folder location on drive C:\. Unfortunately, I always get the error 'Accesss is denied'. I have no problems saving on other drives like D:\ or E:\. Is it possible to backup the database without modifying server permissions? Preferably through code using c#.

I am using Transact-SQL.

My query is something like this:

```
BACKUP DATABASE dbTest  
TO DISK = 'C:\Desktop\dbTest.Bak' (Let's assume this is the path to desktop)
```

I already tried running the app on administrator, results is still "Access is denied"

Comment: SQL Server or Sybase?

Comment: Your database user which is running the DB instance should have the right to write to C drive, else it isn't possible!

Comment: What do you mean by "on desktop"? You do realise SQL Server backups are local to the server, not the client? Also, the user running the instance has to have permissions to write in the specified directory.

Comment: Did you try run the app in admin if possible if not why not use the **ApplicationData** folder as that is what it is designed for? `string MyPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);`

Comment: You simply need to find a folder that the user running the database server has access to.  You can probably adjust permissions on an existing folder.

Comment: @CodeCaster - You may take DB backups on different locations as well!

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful what do you mean by "different locations"?

Comment: There are a few method.  1) You can detach the database from the server and then copy mdf file.  Then reattach 2) You can archive the database by right clicking database in SQL Server Management Studio 3) You can use one of the command line tools like BCP.exe or SQLCMD.exe.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine

Comment: @CodeCaster - I meant something like [this - How to take database backup into another PC in Sql Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21373405/how-to-take-database-backup-into-another-pc-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful yes, so the relevant term you mean is "to an UNC path". That doesn't change anything of what I said, you still need the appropriate permissions.

Comment: @CodeCaster - I raised the point where you claim that `...You do realise SQL Server backups are local to the server, not the client...`; this is what I highlighted as **not necessarily true**. Please review your comment.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful notice the word "local". If you use a local path, you're going to write to the server that SQL Server is running on. Yes, you can use UNC paths, but you're not going to open shares on your clients and allow a SQL Server user to write to that, hopefully?

Comment: @CodeCaster - *...but you're not going to open shares on your clients and allow a SQL Server user to write to that, hopefully?...* - Someone may feel that way, though, I agree that would not be a good thought process!

Answer (score 0):

When you back up a SQL Server database, the path you provide is on the server, not the client (assuming local, not UNC).

So if you want to put the backup files on the desktop of the currently logged in user (assuming console or Remote Desktop access to the server), then the user running the SQL Server instance has to have permissions to write to the path specified.

By default, user X (the SQL Server user) cannot write in directories owned by user Y (the Remote Desktop user).

So:

> without modifying server permissions?

No.

Comment: Is there an alternative way? My app goes something like this, the user selects the file location where the backup is to be saved. The backup is successfully saved on other drives except C:\.

Comment: It's still very unclear what you're trying to do. What is your use case? Why do you let users select a location? Where is this location, on the database server or on the user's machine? But again, no permissions = no writing. That's not going to change.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details, anyway... (1) my goal is to create a backup of the database in .bak file format. (2) The reason being so they can save it on their flashdrives or wherever they want. (3) the database is a local database  and the location is the user's machine.

Comment: My experience with giving users a backup option is that they don't take that option, and you get a phone call in the middle of the night whether you can recover their data. Anyway, the point still remains the same: the SQL Server instance is running under a certain user account, and **that user account can by default not write to another user account's desktop**. Period.